# How to get mysql hostname on remote server

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','mozaik-matria');
```

The above is part of `çonfig.php` and it works on localhost.
Moving on remote server I cannot find any info (using cpanel and phpMyAdmin) about `DBHOST` parameter.

I tried with pure url (`http://example.com/`) and subdomain (`http://subdomain.example.com/`) - without success:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host...`

Comment: Contact your remote server admin for above information.

Comment: It's likely just `localhost`, if that doesn't work try `example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of the server like godaddy. the hostname as localhost are work fine.

But you can use example.com as hostname.

And user name you can find from the database wizard. if username does not exist than you have to create user. And same for the database.

Exa:

```
define('DBHOST','example.com');
define('DBUSER','username');
```

Answer (score 1):

on c panel there will be an option for databases select database and create user credentials and then use localhost as dbhost

if you db is deploy on other host then use that url [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqKEX.png)

Answer (score 0):

idk, is this help ? :

`mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Can't Connect To DBase');`
`mysql_select_db('mozaik-matria');`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out the hostname for your MySQL database is to go to your cPanel -> phpMyAdmin and it will be listed there for you.

Comment: Where is listed ? I can't see any info about hostname inside phpMyAdmin.

Comment: It is shown twice, once on top of the page and then to the right side where your MySQL version is listed: http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/16/0630/h_1467286430_3307805_1f230637e0.png

Answer (score 0):

To connect the remote database, you have to add the port **3306** for the mysql and don't forget to specify the username and password of the database.

```
mysql_connect('your_my_sql_servername or IP Address', 'new_user_which_u_created', 'password');
```